# Mac + External drive not recognized as removable storage

Tags: macos, removable-storage

I have a external 1TB drive which is not getting recognized by my program as removable storage device.

I have in my code the following lines to detect the removable drives attached to the machine.

NSArray *removableDrivesPaths = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedRemovableMedia];

Please can you guys tell me a method to get my external drives get detected as removable storage devices or if there is any other cocoa framework function that i can use to detect my external drives as removable storage devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Removable" media is one that is physically distinct from the drive it is placed within - i.e. a floppy or a CD drive.  So this is correct in not returning external hard drives.  I'm not sure how you would go about finding the information you want, though.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from OS X 10.7, NSURL API has two keys `NSURLVolumeIsLocalKey` and `NSURLVolumeIsInternalKey`. External drives should be local, but not internal. Also `NSURLVolumeIsInternalKey` must be not `nil` (it is nil for mounted disk images).

```c
NSError *error;
NSArray *resourceKeys = @[NSURLVolumeIsLocalKey, NSURLVolumeIsInternalKey];
NSDictionary *valuesDict = [volumeURL resourceValuesForKeys:resourceKeys error:&error];
if (valuesDict != nil) {
    NSNumber *isLocal = valuesDict[NSURLVolumeIsLocalKey];
    NSNumber *isInternal = valuesDict[NSURLVolumeIsInternalKey];
    if (isLocal != nil && isInternal != nil) {
        BOOL isExternal = [isLocal boolValue] && ![isInternal boolValue];
        NSLog(@"Drive external: %d", isExternal);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error getting resource for volume URL: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you'd just like to access files from the device it should appear as a drive under /Volumes.

Comment: I have an app which should launch only from external removable storage devices like usb drives. All drives are shown under /Volumes but my app should check if it is launched from a removable storage device. so it checks its launch path to match if its a removable storage path.